# Pyspark - How to plot streaming data

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to plot line graph of my data while streaming. Since streamed data type DStream i cannot use it, i only managed to print it.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

sc = SparkContext("local[2]","test")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 3)
socket_stream = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost",50007)
random_integers = socket_stream.window( 9 )
digits = random_integers.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).map(lambda digit: (digit, 1))

digit_count = digits.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)
digit_count_sorted_dstream = digit_count.transform((lambda foo:foo.sortBy(lambda x:( -x[1]))))

digit_count_sorted_dstream.pprint()
```

the output look like this:

```
[("1",5),("2",4),("3",8),("4",6),("5",9),("6",3)]
```